# When should comments be moved to chat?

Tags: discussion, moderators

If you look at the comments here:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84791/discussion-on-question-by-viclib-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-represent-sma

I fail to see why the comments were moved

I had thought it was only when two people were going back and forth

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm the one that moved the comments, it's only fair that I answer.

The comments were moved because of the 'extended discussion'.

Comments are for:

- Clarification
- Adding more information that should be in the post.

In this case, the comments were a meta discussion about the question and about the various approaches in the question; they weren't asking for clarification; they were discussing the various approaches presented.

Since that's not what the comments are for (and we received multiple system flags on that post), the comments were moved to chat so that if people still wanted to have that meta-discussion, they could in a format where such things don't raise flags.

It's also important to note that I pruned the comments before moving the discussion over, so even all the comments you see there aren't all the comments that were on that question. Nine other comments were deleted for various reasons; most because they duplicated things already said.